# How to update database with ajax textarea

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-events

I can't figure it out how I can update the database with this textarea. Can somebody help?

**The ajaxcall**

```
$$('.btn').addEvent('click', function() {
var request = new Request( {
                        url: '<?php echo $baselink;?>',
                        method: 'post',
                        onSuccess:function(responseText) { alert(responseText);},
                        data: {                    
                        'name' : this.id,
                        'value' : this.value,
                        'tmpl':'component',
                        'format':'raw',
                        'ajax' : 1
                        }
}).send();});


**//Form//**
$s6=$item['Select6'];
$id=$item['items_id'];
print '<form method="post" class="formulier">
<input maxlength="250" NAME="name" class="name" id="'.$id.'" value="'.$s6.'" SIZE="50">
<input type="submit" value="Click me" class="btn"/></form>';
```

**Query**

```
if(JRequest::getVar('ajax') ) {  
$state=JRequest::getInt('value','oeps');    
$id=JRequest::getVar('name','');   
if ( $id ) {  
$state=(int)$state;  
$query="UPDATE #__dataitems set `Select6`='".$state."' where `items_id`=".$id;    
$db->query();
echo ' Bijgwerkt naar '.$state.' '.$id;
exit;}
```

Comment: did you try adding a textarea? did you try getting value from the textarea?

Comment: I still need the radio option but i need a extra textarea to update the $Select6 in the database. I made a textarea but i can't figure it out how i can update the database with same construction of the ajaxcall ;( :D

Answer (score 0):

You are currently listening on the radio button click and send the event when it does.

You need to add a button/href to your form and bind an click event to it, and then once it is clicked, just collect the data from the radio button and the textarea and send it:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="button" value="Click me" class="btn"/>
```

**JS:**

```
$$('.btn').addEvent('click', function(){
var radioId = ...//get radio id
var radioVal = ...//get val
var textarea = ... //get textarea val
var request = new Request( {
                            url: '<?php echo $baselink;?>',
                            method: 'post',
                            onSuccess:function(responseText) { alert(responseText);},
                            data: {
                            'volgorde' : radioId,
                            'check' : radioVal,
                            'textarea' : textarea ,
                            'tmpl':'component',
                            'format':'raw',
                            'ajax' : 1
                            }
    }).send();});
```

I'm guessing you are using prototypejs (because of the `$$`), i don't know it very well so i can't help you with how to get the elements id and values, but this is the direction.

Comment: Thanks @ftom2, now i have to figure out how i can update the $Select6. Somebody have some suggestions?

Comment: So where is the problem, you are sending the data in the ajax request, fetching it in your script and saving it, just like you did with the radio button?!

Comment: So again, i don't get the problem, you don't know how to update the DB or you don't know how to get the value from DB?\

Comment: I know how to load the value from the DB but i don't now how to update the value from the textarea to the field $Select6 in the DB, again thanks for your help ftom2

Comment: Don't you have a query that updates the DB with value from the radio button? just do the same but with value from the textarea: `Update some_table set section6 = $textareaVal where id = $id`. i really don't understand the problem.

Comment: Bummer, i updated the question what i have untill so far but it doesn't work

Comment: First of all you are missing some spaces in the query: `where'items_id'`, secondly, you have not updated the script that is sending the ajax request, you are not sending the textarea value

Comment: With the radio option it sends but i don't know how to post the value from the textarea.

Comment: I tested your answer but it's not working, what do i have to fill in on the

var textarea = ...